# HTML: Post form from http to https

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

We have this code on http://soAndSo.com/path/abc.aspx page:

```
<form id="MainForm" name="MainForm" method="post" action="xyz.aspx">
```

now we need to redirect user to https://soAndSo.com/path/xyz.aspx.
The problem is we can't use full URL because we need to use same code in all environments.
Any idea how can we achive this using html and javascript?

Comment: Don't do that.  It defeats the purpose of HTTPS.

Comment: How does it defeat the purpose of https?  If the form data is posted via https, how would the form contents be compromised?

Comment: @recursive: The attacker can intercept the original page and make it submit to his own site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in plain HTML.

With client-side JavaScript, you can `document.getElementById('MainForm').action = somevalue;` where `somevalue` is computed based on the value of `location.href`.

In general, you would be better off achieving this with a server side language.

However: Data entered on an HTTP page is **not secure**. It will be secured before transit over HTTPS, but the HTTP page containing the form could be interfered with in transit **to** the user (e.g. so that the submission would be sent to a different server).

You should redirect from the HTTP URI that is currently hosting the document with the `<form>` to a copy of that document on HTTPS.